# Inputting specific values into matrices by using a function

Tags: python, if-statement, matrix

How do I write a function in Python which takes as input the **basic salary(basic)** **and** **number of hours of overtime worked(overtime).** The function should return as **output a matrix with five rows and six columns**. All entries of the matrix should be rounded to the nearest whole number. Each row corresponds to an employee, and

• the first column should contain the employee number,

• the second column contains their basic salary,

• the third column contains their deductions for November,

• the fourth column contains the number of hours overtime worked,

• the fifth column contains their overtime pay, and

• the sixth column contains their net salary for November.

The value of the ratio of deduction(written as **deduction** in code) and overtime rate(**otrate**) which is money earned per hour of overtime work varies on the value of the basic salary. Here is a basic code that I constructed to convey the information:

```
 if (basic < 3000):
    deduction = 0.15
    otrate = 20
    netsalary = basic * (1-deduction) + (overtime * otrate)
elif (basic < 5000):
    deduction = 0.21
    otrate = 40
    netsalary = basic * (1-deduction) + (overtime * otrate)
elif (basic < 8000):
    deduction = 0.27
    otrate = 60
    netsalary = basic * (1-deduction) + (overtime * otrate)
else:
    deduction = 0.33
    otrate = 80
    netsalary = basic * (1-deduction) + (overtime * otrate)
```

(fourth column) Deduction amount = Basic salary * ratio of deduction

(fifth column) Overtime pay = Hours worked overtime * rate of overtime pay

Net salary = basic salary * (1 - ratio of deduction) + hours worked overtime * overtime rate

Answer (score 0):

I think the following Python script could be your solution.

```
class BasicSalary:
    def __init__(self, deduction, otrate):
        self.salary = 0
        self.overtime = 0
        self.deduction = deduction
        self.otrate = otrate

    @property
    def net_salary(self):
        return self.salary * (1-self.deduction) + (self.overtime * self.otrate)

    @property
    def over_time_pay(self):
        return self.overtime * self.otrate


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, worker_id, name, salary, overtime):
        self.id = worker_id
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.overtime = overtime


if __name__ == '__main__':
    workers = (
        Worker(1, "John", 2900, 80),
        Worker(2, "Judith", 3100, 30),
        Worker(3, "Vlad", 4900, 45),
        Worker(4, "Zlotan", 5100, 36),
        Worker(5, "Corinne", 7900, 12),
        Worker(6, "Pjer", 8200, 5)
    )
    table = []
    for worker in workers:
        if worker.salary < 3000:
            basic = BasicSalary(0.15, 20)
        elif worker.salary < 5000:
            basic = BasicSalary(0.21, 40)
        elif worker.salary < 8000:
            basic = BasicSalary(0.27, 60)
        else:
            basic = BasicSalary(0.33, 80)
        basic.salary = worker.salary
        basic.overtime = worker.overtime
        row = (worker.id, worker.salary, basic.deduction, worker.overtime, basic.over_time_pay, basic.net_salary)
        table.append(row)
    print(table)
```

**Note:** don't use parantheses in condition, this is unnecessary.

## Edit

This could be a simpler way:

```
workers = (
      {'id': 1, 'name': "John", 'salary': 2900, 'overtime': 80},
      {'id': 2, 'name': "Judith", 'salary': 3100, 'overtime': 30},
      {'id': 3, 'name': "Vlad", 'salary': 4900, 'overtime': 45},
      {'id': 4, 'name': "Zlotan", 'salary': 5100, 'overtime': 36},
      {'id': 5, 'name': "Corinne", 'salary': 7900, 'overtime': 12},
      {'id': 6, 'name': "Pjer", 'salary': 8200, 'overtime': 5}
)
table = []
for worker in workers:
    if worker['salary'] < 3000:
        deduction = 0.15
        otrate = 20
    elif worker['salary'] < 5000:
        deduction = 0.21
        otrate = 40
    elif worker['salary'] < 8000:
        deduction = 0.27
        otrate = 60
    else:
        deduction = 0.33
        otrate = 80
    overtime_pay = (worker['overtime'] * otrate)
    net_salary = worker['salary'] * (1 - deduction) + overtime_pay
    row = (worker['id'], worker['salary'], deduction, worker['overtime'], overtime_pay, net_salary)
    table.append(row)
print(table)
```

Note that three last lines are the same becuase these are the clue. Assignment of `row` is that you was requested. Each row contains the 6 elements.

The expression `worker['salary'] * (1 - deduction) + (worker['overtime'] * otrate)` is the same and is repeated in all *if*/*elif* statments, you can put this once when they end. I profit that `(worker['overtime'] * otrate)` is the *overtime_pay* result to assign it before *net_salary* and retrieve it in other places (in next assignment of `net_salary`, and in `row` assignment).

Comment: Is there an alternative way where I use np.zeros.reshape(5,6) and for loops only. Sorry but this seems to advanced for me

Comment: I've added simplest way.